# How to use an enumeration and pattern for phone in xsd?

Tags: xml, design-patterns, xsd, phone-number, enumerated-types

The problem is requesting the following. That the phone should have the attribute type with 3 enumerated values of home, cell, and work. AND the phone should also be restricted to a phone format of (###) ###-####.
How do you combine the attribute for enumerated vales AND apply a restricted pattern?
XML example:

```xml
<donor level="founder">
    <name>David Brennan</name>
    <address>5133 Oak Street
             Windermere, FL  34786</address>
    <phone type="home">(407) 555-8981</phone>
    <phone type="cell">(407) 555-8189</phone>
    <email>dbrennan@delisp.net</email>
    <donation>50000.00</donation>
    <method>Phone</method>
    <effectiveDate>1982-09-01</effectiveDate>
</donor>
```

xsd code I have so far for phone:

```xml
<xs:attribute name="type" type="pType" />

<xs:simpleType name="phoneType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
    
<xs:element name="phone">
    <xs:complexType>  
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base ="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute ref="type" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="pType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="home" />
        <xs:enumeration value="cell" />
        <xs:enumeration value="work" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="donor">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="name"/>
            <xs:element ref="address"/>
            <xs:element ref="phone" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="email" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element ref="donation" />
            <xs:element ref="method" />
            <xs:element ref="effectiveDate" />
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="level" />
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. But you missed to use the `phoneType` definition in your element's type assignment: just change the (`base`)type in `<xs:extension base ="xs:string">` making your `phone` element definition

```
<xs:element name="phone">
    <xs:complexType>  
      <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base ="phoneType">
          <xs:attribute ref="type" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Now everything should work as desired and your RegEx definition should restrict the string values.